# C# IEnumerable.toArray() in O(1)

Tags: c#, big-o, toarray

I have been playing around with the BlockingCollection class, and I was wondering why the ToArray() Method is an O(n) operation. Coming from a Java background, the ArrayList's ToArray() method runs in O(1), because it just returns the internal array it uses (elementData). So why in the world do they iterate through all of the items, and create a new Array in the IEnumerable.ToArray method, when they could just override it and return the internal array the collection uses?

Comment: You wouldn't, usually, want to return the array the is wrapped within a collection, because that could cause troubles.

Comment: You are assuming that all collections in .NET are backed by arrays.

Comment: I would venture to guess that it's because the `Enumerable.ToArray()` is a generic method that has no idea of the `BlockingCollection`'s internals.  And so it does it the only way *it knows it can do it*, and that's by iterating the collection.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - That's my point. Most. Not all. Meaning that you can't guarantee `O(1)`.

Comment: @Oded The BlockingColleciton class could easily override the method and return it's internal array structure. I am not assuming all structures use arrays (even though most do), I was referring specifically to the BlockingCollection<T> class, which in fact, does use an internal array.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera - Until they change it in .NET 8.0.

Comment: @Oded But putting aside the fact that it's bad doing that in O(1), etc, and consider the hypothetical situation where you have certain collections that have ToArray methods in O(1), then the IEnumerable could check it's internal collection's type and cast it to appropriate type and return it's double-internal array, if it's internal collection is of a type which supports that, for extra efficiency. So the assumption that all collection are one way or another is irrelevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Coming from a Java background, the ArrayList's ToArray() method runs in O(1), because it just returns the internal array it uses (elementData).

No, it really doesn't. It creates a copy of the array. From [the docs for `ArrayList.toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29):

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element).
>
> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by this list. (In other words, this method must allocate a new array). The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

So basically, the premise of your question is flawed in the Java sense.

Now, beyond that, [`Enumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) (the extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`) *in general* would be O(N), as there's no guarantee that the sequence is even backed by an array. When it's backed by an `IList<T>`, it uses [`IList<T>.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw.aspx) to make things more efficient, but this is an implementation-specific detail and still doesn't transform it into an O(1) operation.

Comment: Also, why does it return a copy?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx

Comment: I think there should be more of a balance, with the option of returning a reference to the internal structure, because if you're in my situation with an array containing millions of elements, a damned copy operation would take forever, and I don't even really need the BlockingCollection<T> anymore, so it wouldn't really matter if I changed its elements in any way...

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera: I don't think you'll find any of the .NET or Java collections which are willing to violate encapsulation in that way.

Answer (score 2):

[`ArrayList.toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) is not **O(1)**, and it does not just return its internal array. Did you read the API specification?

> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by this list. (In other words, this method must allocate a new array). The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no array to return. `BlockingCollection<T>` uses an object of type `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` for its internal storage, and there's no guarantee that the concrete type being used will be backed by an array.  For example the default constructor uses a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which stores its data in a linked list of arrays.  Even in the odd case where there is an array which represents the full contents of the collection hiding somewhere in there it won't be exposed through the `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` interface.

Second, even assuming there were an array to be returned in the first place (which there isn't), it wouldn't be a safe thing to do.  If the calling code made any modifications to the array it would corrupt the internal state of the collection.